# Rails - Updating a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

using heroku, I'm trying to update a record.

This is what I did:

```
@user = User.find(11)
@user.email = 'xxx@xxx.com'
@user.save
>> true
```

But then when I do User.find(11), the email isn't updated? Any ideas why?

Comment: Is that the exact code? Cause you didn't close the quotation on the email.

Comment: that was a typo. updated

Comment: Is this what happens in the console or is there other code related to this that you haven't included?

Comment: Try this, `User.find(11).update_attribute("email","xxx@xxx.com")` Also check to see that the email you are passing wouldn't contradict any validations you may silently erroring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend trying `@user.reload` after you hit `@user.save`. The suggestion above to try `@user.save!` (read - "@user dot save bang") is also a good one because it will throw an error if a validation fails when saving `@user`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also try `@user.save!` which will give a error if any validations go wrong. But if `@user.save` give true, then I dont see any reason why it is not saved into the db.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `true` then you don't really have to worry about the record not being validated. True tells you it did get saved. But it is a good practice to use `@user.save!` like @rubyprince mentioned. That way, invalid update attempts will be raised.

Also, are you sure it's not getting updated? If you're using a database backend I'd go directly to the database rather than relying on an `User.find()`

You can also try doing `User.find(11).reload` to see if that works. You can find some info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload) about `reload`. So you can try something like this...

```
user = User.find(11).reload
puts user.email
```

And see if the email changed.